# Unable to cd into a grepped directory

Tags: grep, cd

I have a volume with spaces and periods that I am unable to cd into

```
bash-4.3$ ll /Volumes
total 8
drwxrwxrwt@  4 root       admin              136 Apr 17 11:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  33 root       wheel             1190 Feb  5 19:05 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root       admin                1 Apr 17 09:41 Macintosh HD -> /
drwxr-xr-x   4 username   wheel   204 Jan 28 02:54 OS X 10.10.2 Update Combo
```

but trying to cd in this way yields

```
bash-4.3$ cd "$(ls /Volumes |grep 'OS X')"
bash: cd: OS X 10.10.2 Update Combo: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does `cd /Volumes/*"OS X"*` work?

Comment: As stated by the error message, there's no "OS X 10.10.2 Update Combo" in your home directory.

Comment: @RC. there is no mention of home directory in my question

Comment: @EtanReisner this works perfectly, please post as a reply and I'll gladly accept

Comment: @ehime s/home/current/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as indicated by RC in their comment is that the output from that command substitution is the bare directory name `OS X 10.10.2 Update Combo` which then is used as `cd "OS X 10.10.2 Update Combo"` but there is no such directory in the current directory. You would need `cd /Volumes/"$(ls /Volumes |grep 'OS X')"` to do what you wanted.

That being said using `ls` and `grep` for this is not at all appropriate. A better solution is simply to use a glob.

```
cd /Volumes/*"OS X"*
```

This will fail (as would the original) if more than one directory/file matches the glob however.